# Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead, when using decision tree

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a data set(19 attributes and 1700 instances),I am training Logistic regression, decision tree, random forest on it. logistic regression works fine but when I try decision trees I get the error:

```
Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
```

```
data = data.interpolate()
print(data.isnull().sum())

data['Year_upd'].fillna('0', inplace=True)
data['Month_upd'].fillna('0', inplace=True)
data['Day_upd'].fillna('0', inplace=True)
data['Hour_upd'].fillna('0', inplace=True)

print(data.isnull().sum())

x = data.drop(labels='Type', axis='columns')
y = data.iloc [:, 13]
x.head()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y ,test_size = 0.2,)
model = LogisticRegression(max_iter = 4000)
model.fit (x_train, y_train)

model3= tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model3.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

I tried using the following code to fix the issue

```
model3= tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model3.fit(x_train.values.reshape(-1, 1),y_train)
```

and I still get: Number of labels=1424 does not match number of samples=29904

Answer (score 0):

`x_train` should be a 2D features matrix with shape `(n_instances, n_features)`. I would recommend converting the tables to NumPy arrays before splitting and testing, like so:

```py
x = data.drop(labels='Type', axis='columns').to_numpy()
y = data.iloc[:, 13].to_numpy()

# ...
model3= tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model3.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Hi, I did as you suggested but I still get the same error.

Comment: Number of labels=1424 does not match number of samples=29904

Comment: What are the shapes of `x_train` and `y_train`?

Comment: y_train.shape (1424,) (x_train.shape) (1424, 21)

Comment: Then it should be working. Are you still flattening the array or something? Obviously you need to remove the `reshape(-1, 1)` if that's still present.

Comment: Hi, yes I removed the reshape but it still caused the error, however I don't know why but splitting the data again before training each model with your suggestion fixed the issue. Thank You.